# Unable to do vector division (every element) and append to a new array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to append the division between two arrays into a new array. But the same value being iteratively stored into the new array.

```
clear; close all; 
%Plot G (small - signal gain) vs v (frequency) 
%Assume frequency probe region to be thrice the line-width
f=input('Line Width Frequency(in Hz) :');
v=(-3*f):10e10:(3*f);
l=length(v);
g=zeros(1,l);
k=zeros(1,l);
h=ones(1,l);
% Substituing the constants we realize g(v) is a function 
% line shaping function
for i=1:l
  k(1:i)=((v(1:i)-2.82*10e-4)+((627.95*10e9)^2)); 
end
g=rdivide(h,k);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning multiple elements of k at once.  Try this:

```
for i=1:l
  k(i)=((v(i)-2.82*10e-4)+((627.95*10e9)^2)); 
end
```

or even more simply, this is a great example of a vectorized operation:

```
k = (v -2.82*10e-4)+((627.95*10e9)^2));  %% works the same as above
```

`k(1:i)` is a slice of the array `k`, containing the elements 1, 2, .. i.  So in the last loop iteration, you assign the entire array k(1:l), wiping out the calculations from previous iterations.

Comment: I am getting the same value as output , my vector v is fine . Check this, Please (thanks!) [link](http://s30.postimg.org/6khxltjf5/Capture.jpg)

Comment: I tried both your suggestions. I'm still getting iterative values . [link](http://s30.postimg.org/6khxltjf5/Capture.jpg) and [link](http://s15.postimg.org/xrjcm02ob/Capture.jpg)

Comment: I got the same values that you posted...I think the problem is the term `(627.95*10e9)^2` dominates your calculation, so the differences don't show up until about the 12 significant figure.  Those are NOT identical values, but they look the same because MATLAB is just displaying the first few significant digits.

Comment: What do you mean by `iterative` values?